# NSMutableDictionary and new items insertion KVO

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

Let me describe my problem first. I have a class which holds a NSMutableDictionary ivar. There is a thread that will add new pairs into this dictionary - at the moment of writing the application I'm not able to have a full list of available keys. An up-to-date list of all this pairs have to be shown in the Table View.
I've prepared small proof of concept application where there is a Dictionary Controller created in the xib file, and its content is binded with the dictionary ivar. The problem is that Table View shows only initial set of the dictionary's content. After insertion it's not refreshed.

In my proof of concept application AppController.h is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject

@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;

- (NSString *)randomString;
- (IBAction)addRandomPair:(id)sender;

@end
```

And the implementation file content:

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController

@synthesize dictionary = _dictionary;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_dictionary setValue:@"Aa" forKey:@"A"];
        [_dictionary setValue:@"Bb" forKey:@"B"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)randomString
{
    NSMutableString *aString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        NSUInteger r = random() % ('z' - 'a');
        [aString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", ('a' +r)]];
    }
    return aString;
}

- (IBAction)addRandomPair:(id)sender
{
    [self.dictionary setValue:[self randomString] forKey:[self randomString]];
    NSLog([self.dictionary description]);
}

@end
```

Dictionary Controller Content is bound to the App Controller with Model Key Path set to "self.dictionary" and columns content in the Table View is bound to Dictionary Controller with Model Key Path set to key and value accordingly. In this proof of concept application button click adds a new pair (addRandomPair: action).

I had a similar problem with a NSMutableArray and Array Controller, but there I was able to solve the problem by adding following pair of methods to the class holding an array ivar (named data in this class):

```
- (void)insertObject:(NSString *)object inDataAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectFromDataAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

**Is it possible to add some other methods to the class holding a dictionary (AppController) to be notified about new insertions? Or maybe there is a better solution for my problem?**

### Update

I've found out that implementing following set of accessors makes Dictionary Controller notified about new item:

```
- (void)addDictionaryObject:(NSString *)object;
- (void)removeDictionaryObject:(NSString *)object;
```

**The problem is that `addDictionaryObject:` has only one argument, dictionary would require something like `addDictionaryObject:forKey:`. Any ideas?**

### Update 2

I don't see any other solution than using manual change notification - in this case `addRandomPair:` method looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)addRandomPair:(id)sender
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"dictionary"];
    [self.dictionary setValue:[self randomString] forKey:[self randomString]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dictionary"];
    NSLog([self.dictionary description]);
}
```

It works, but I'm still a bit uncertain since dictionary itself will not change, but its content. **Is using manual change notification a correct approach here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Key-Value Coding methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE) document, only `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableSet` is supported for To-Many properties.  Since, KVC already works with keys, it would be redundant to have `NSMutableDictionary` supported since it's effectively what `setValue:forKey:` already does.

Maybe override `setValue:forKeyPath:` if you really want this in one call.

Comment: Hard to say if it would be redundant. In my case I wouldn't say that it would be redundant, dictionary here is just a data structure. I could use let's say NSMutableArray and store in it key and value within a new Data class. From the KVO point of view it wouldn't be redundant, but for me it would decrease performance since for every update of value it would require to iterate whole collection...

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this.  You have an object holding a Dictionary and you're try to both access it, and specify a value for a key in a single call.  It would be much easier to just split this in two KVC calls : one to get the Dictionary (like you would any property) , and then `setValue:forKey:` on the dictionary.

Otherwise, maybe override `setValue:forKeyPath:` of the controller.

Comment: Today I've studied Key-Value Coding Programming Guide carefully and you are right only NSMutableArray and NSMutableSet support to-many properties. Now I'm going to design a class containing a dictionary but have all accessor methods to be compilant with KVO and behave like NSMutableArray. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call something like

```
 [_tableView reloadData];
```

That will tell your tableview to essentially refresh everything it knows.

Comment: I know that it's possible, but in my real application it would break MVC pattern - I don't want to have an outlet in my DataManager class. Some way to go would be using block which would call `realoadData:` method but I feel that KVO it designed to deal with problems like mine.

Comment: @Krokodylowy : AppController must be a controller class (otherwise you are already breaking the pattern).  It doesn't break MVC to send `-reloadData` in `-addRandomPair:`

Comment: @JeremyP the source coude posted in the question is only a **proof of concept** application. Real application has a Model where is a DataManager, model is handled by ModelController (facade design pattern), AppController has an ivar of the ModellController and there are also several windows (for each there is a custom NSWindowController class) so I would really like to use KVO instead of calling `reloadData:`.